1970's live action, Sat morning show which ship containing multiple civilizations in pods
1970's live action, Sat morning show which has the feel of the new movie Passengers.  
Many civilizations living within different pods, on a large ship that is drifting in space with a dead crew.  
After a period of exploring how to move around on the ship, and finding out that they are not alone, the few people that are looking for the answers to where they are going find out that the entire ship is on auto-pilot and the crew has been dead for a long time.  
What is this??

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Sounds like this could be "The Starlost", a 1970s series that, despite being created by science fiction legend Harlan Ellison and with Ben Bova as a science advisor, is sometimes described as one of the worst science fiction series ever made (not necessarily due to either of those two... Ellison was so frustrated he asked his name be taken off and was credited as Cordwainer Bird). 

From the plot description on Wikipedia, we hit some of the main points of your recollection:

Foreseeing the destruction of the Earth, humanity builds a multi-generational starship called Earthship Ark, 50 miles (80 km) wide and 200 miles (320 km) long. The ship contains dozens of biospheres, each kilometres across and housing people of different cultures; their goal is to find and seed a new world of a distant star. In 2385, more than one hundred years into the voyage, an unexplained accident occurs, and the ship goes into emergency mode, whereby each biosphere is sealed off from the others.

The above quote covers the many civilizations living in different pods, and as for the bridge crew being dead and the ship on autopilot:

Eventually they make their way to the ship's bridge, containing the skeletal remains of its crew. It is badly damaged and its control systems are inoperative. The three discover that the Ark is on a collision course with a Class G star similar to the Sun, and realize that the only way to save The Ark and its passengers is to find the backup bridge and reactivate the navigation and propulsion systems. Occasionally, they are aided by the ship's partially functioning computer system.

The show did air on Saturdays.  Its first airing, according to Wikipedia, was on September 22nd, 1973, which was indeed a Saturday, although I can't guarantee it was in the morning.  It was also syndicated, which means that different areas likely played it on different days and times.  A commenter on this page specifically recalls watching it Saturday mornings in reruns (although he remembers it in the 80s, considering it was Canadian and Canadian broadcasters have laws requiring a certain amount of TV be devoted to Canadian shows, it might well have run well into the 80s just filling airtime).  

Thank YOU!
Yes, this is the show that I remember from that time period!  I found episodes online and will watch just for 'fun'.
Just for grins... Take a look at the premise of the new movie Passengers and tell me what you think.   ?? Match ??

@DanteJ I can certainly see some similarities, yeah.  But since this is the correct answer, if you come back this way please click the check mark button beside this answer (underneath the up and down vote buttons), which marks the answer as "correct" and so people looking at question lists see that it's been solved, rather than just attempted.

I also discovered this show via those Saturday morning reruns.  There was s a DVD release but I doubt it will ever see Bluray.
